# Am i doing something wrong? PHP Apache mod_rewrite 1 second lag to load jquery ajax success.

Tags: php, ajax, apache, performance, mod-rewrite

When sending an ajax call to a site that has mod_rewrite enabled i am getting a success return after avg 800ms. If i send an ajax call to a site with no mod_rewrite i am getting a success return after avg 3ms. Below is some code used that is creating this slow success call. How can i fix this please?

-----apache httpd.config file------

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Careplan/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

-----apache httpd.config file------

-----index.php view------

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({  
     url : "http://localhost/Controller/method/", 
     method:"GET",  
     data:{},  
     dataType: 'json',
     success:function(data){  
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - start); //THIS SHOWS THE 800ms
        console.log(data);
     }
});
```

-----apache httpd.config file------

-----controller file returning json----

```
class Controller {
    public function method(){
       echo json_encode('testing testing 123...');
    }
}
```

-----controller file returning json----

Comment: Does the lag occur if you visit the URL using your web browser?

Comment: no the php controller script loads under 1ms. the 800ms lag only occurs when loading the php controller script via mod_rewrite which is needed for my MVC setup.

Comment: Okay, let me re-phrase. With mod_rewrite enabled, does the lag occur if you visit http://localhost/Controller/method/ using your web browser too or just when using AJAX?

Comment: Also, is this CodeIgniter?

Comment: Additionally, you can time AJAX calls by using the Network Tab of your Developer Tools

Comment: With mod_rewrite enabled and going to localhost/Controller/method looking at the Network Tab of the Developer Tools still results in 810ms. Not using any frameworks for PHP.

Comment: That is just weird. I would enable `debug` mode for your Apache logs and see if anything sticks out.

Comment: Problem solved! Seems my 1st reply to you was wrong. Issue was all PHP scripts were loading at an avg of 400ms and this was because i had enabled Xdebug module for visual studio code.

Comment: Thanks for all the help MonkeyZeus the back and forth helped a lot!

Comment: I see, well I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

All PHP scripts were running slow because Xdebug PHP module was enabled. Once commented out of php.ini and resetting web server all scripts started loading avg of 3ms.